# Bot Chat Application Registration -AZURE

Tags: asp.net, azure, botframework

I have created a Bot Chat Application on ASP .NET. I want to integrate it to other application but from the available tutorials, I can not register on Azure. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q517t.png)

Comment: If you are unable to register for Azure you should contact Azure support

Comment: @JasonSowers thanks but I have tried all ways to register though still failing. Card verification step is not validating after trying two cards. I gave up. The service is limiting to some extend.

Comment: Definitely contact Azure support

Comment: You know of any live support #Azure @JasonSowers.

Comment: If you have a twitter, I would tweet at them https://twitter.com/AzureSupport they are very responsive there  also there is a chat window for support on this website https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to have a azure subscription to create a azure resource. Click on 'Sign up for a new subscription' and follow the steps to get a subscription and then to create/register a bot.